# using an if statement inside a while with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, while-loop

Hi guys I'm using a while loop to display my posts and while I have posts I want to display the odd and even post numbers differently.  I currently have the following code:

```
    <div class="container">
      <?php if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
        yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>');
      } ?> 
    </div>
    <?php query_posts('post_type=portfolio&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=8&paged='. get_query_var('paged'));
      if( have_posts() ):
        echo '<div>';
      if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
          $wp_query->the_post();
      $i = 0;
      if($i % 2 == 0)
      {?>
        <div class="class1">
          html content 1 to go here
        </div>
        <?php
          $i++;
      }else{
        ?>
        <div class="class2">
          html content 2 to go here
        </div>
        <?php $i++; } ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navigation">
            <span class="newer"><?php previous_posts_link(__('« See Previous Case Studies','example')) ?></span> 
            <span class="older"><?php next_posts_link(__('See Next Case Studies »','example')) ?></span>
          </div>
        </div>  <!-- /.navigation -->
        <?php else: ?>
        <div id="post-404" class="noposts">
          <p><?php _e('None found.','example'); ?></p>
        </div><!-- /#post-404 -->
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I haven't used php for a while, so I'm unsure the best way to do the above. I'm currently getting a few errors relating to syntax such as unexpected end of file or unexpected } on line...

Can anyone figure out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Yes, **you** can see where you are going wrong. "currently getting a few errors relating to syntax" is not very helpful: what errors as what location in your source code?

Comment: Apart from error couple of things you did wrong $i = 0; should be outside While loop and also i doubt position of $i++;

Answer (score 0):

Reverse Position

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

First While statement should get complete than if.